# Difference between tomcat http-bio and ajp-bio threads

Tags: web-services, tomcat

I was going through a thread dump of a tomcat 7 application running with Apache server. I saw threads named 'ajp-bio-8009-exec' and 'http-bio-8080-exec'. What is the difference between them? I know that AJP is a protocol that the Tomcat connector BIO uses.